# ggplot2 install not finding new Rcpp, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, ggplot2

I've just upgraded R to 3.1.1, done update packages, and made sure that Rcpp is now 11.2 but getting this error when attempting to upgrade ggplot2.

Ubuntu 14.04 system

namespace ‘Rcpp’ 0.10.6 is being loaded, but >= 0.11.0 is required

Any suggestions?
Thanks, J

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$ sudo R # type this in a terminal

> install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE) # you type this into the R prompt and choose a mirror site
```